# Conditional ActivePivot Configuration

Tags: activepivot

I'm setting up a polymorphic cube on top of a horizontal one as described on the confluence site (http://support.quartetfs.com/confluence/display/AP4/Polymorphic+scalability+on+top+of+horizontal+scalability), but it anoys me that it seems I need to have one of the horizontal nodes configured differently from all the others (the one that participates in the polymorphic cluster). It is quite convenient to be able to deploy the same configuration to all the nodes of the horizontal cluster.

Going all the way back to the spring configuration, I guess I could make a conditional configuration to get around this, but does anyone have a more elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all your nodes to have the same configuration, you could define a polymorphic pivot on each node with the autoStart property set to false (please refer to http://support.quartetfs.com/confluence/display/AP4/Distribution%27s+properties#Distributionsproperties-autoStart). 
However, you'll then have to start one of them: this can be achieved by using the monitoring beans for instance.

Another possibility would be to deploy your horizontal nodes "as usual", then start an additional "proxy" node which will participate to both horizontal and polymorphic clusters. This extra node does not need any data: it's basically an empty horizontal pivot with a polymorphic pivot on top of it.

Comment: Thanks. The autoStart property works well for me. I'm doing the Spring configuration in code, so it is easy for me to do a conditional start of the messenger. Actually I'm tempted to hook this into JGroups leader election of the underlying horizontal cluster, to automatically have a node elected as the one to participate in the polymorphic cluster, but that will be another day.